# ionic5 capacitor app works on lower versions of android 7, 8 but does not work on android 10

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am doing my first ionic project and my android app is working on lower versions of android but not on 10 and higher so wanted to know if I have to change some settings to fix this bug.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error its giving? Is it build failture or http requests failture. Please clarify

Comment: on a OnePlus 5T it is a requests failure issue and on a Samsun on5 Pro its a build failure

Comment: On request failture its from https, but on build fail you should post the output of failture.

Comment: right now my api endpoints are http so for requests failure are you hinting that I should have an https api endpoint instead of an http api endpoint?

Comment: Yes , for all new devices of android of sdk version 28+, requests are forced to be https, but what is build failture?

Comment: I will send it in 10-15 mins

Comment: Okz , recomment when you add it..

Comment: actually the build is happening now .. i have some dates which are null on weekends and i was doing some operation on null hence maybe the build was failing .. you may post converting http to https for apis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sdk versions 28+, android requests are forced to be https so change tour requests from http to https.